# More quickly ingest data from mongo into python

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I have the following data read:

```
print datetime.datetime.now()

opts = m.get_unique_dates_for_underlying(ticker, "date")

print datetime.datetime.now()
```

With the following output:

```
2015-11-02 22:46:50.371000
2015-11-02 22:46:50.371000
```

Now when I go to read the data into my dataframe it takes 12 minutes when running:

```
df_opts = pd.DataFrame(list(opts)).convert_objects()
```

Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

`df_opts` is of length 351,500.

Comment: Does `m.get_unique_dates_for_underlying` return a generator ? If so, that would explain why that returns 'instantly' whereas when you're packing it into your DataFrame you are casting it into a list which Python then needs to iterate over all the objects, 351,500 of them, and create a list. If it is a generator, can you not let pandas load from a generator so you get to skip the explicit creation of a massive list ?

Comment: @ChristianWitts I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249736/how-to-import-data-from-mongodb-to-pandas regarding my use of list(cursor)

Comment: From reading around it seems an issue. Have you tried [monary](https://bitbucket.org/djcbeach/monary/wiki/Home)?

Comment: @Leb thank yes i discovered monary during my commute after posting this question. Thank you for the additional momentum to go that route.