# Pymongo significantly slower than mongo shell?

Tags: python, mongodb, shell, pymongo

I'm relatively new to mongodb, and having a performance problem in pymongo. I have a collection that's 50 GBs (uncompressed) 20 GBs (compressed via WiredTiger) with about 39 million documents. Querying it over indexed fields gives a result that's about 125,000 documents and 150 MBs uncompressed. When I do the following in the mongo shell, it takes about a second.

```
var result = db.my_collection.find(my_query).toArray()
```

However, when I do the same thing in pymongo, it takes over 7 seconds.

```
db = pymongo.MongoClient()['my_db']
result = list(db['my_collection'].find(my_query))
```

Some extra info:

- I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.6, pymongo 3.2, and mongo 3.2.
- I think my pymongo is configured to use C because I installed python-dev and both pymongo.has_c() and bson.has_c() show True.
- Everything is run locally.

I find it hard to believe that pymongo is 7x slower than the mongo shell. What am I missing?

Comment: Try running it with a profiler and check if the time is spent in the python-client side.  Also, you might want to check out Monary: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20693013/2096752

Comment: probably python utf8 string decoding (https://emptysqua.re/blog/an-enlightening-failure/)  "it was eight times faster" -> until he called Python's utf8 decoder.

Comment: @Brandt, did you eventually figure out the problem? I am a facing a worse speed penalty between mongoshell and PyMongo.

Comment: @clocker I never really got to the bottom of this. Instead, since it seemed that the time spent was mostly dominated by converting mongo documents into Python objects, I adopted a "take only out of mongo what you absolutely need" mentality/guideline. I put more emphasis on using pipelines and do as much filtering and processing as I can in mongo before returning the resulting data to Python. Hope that's a little helpful, at least!

Answer (score 0):

There can be one or more of the following reasons that can lead to such behavior.

1. The load on the database at the time of query execution and the sequence in which you are performing these 2 operations can greatly impact the response time for the queries. For example - if you query using pymongo first, it's possible that WiredTiger loads the data from disk. While executing the same query from mongo shell, data is already present in WiredTiger cache(because of the first query made using pymongo).
2. When querying database with pymongo client, the first request is usually very slow compared to the subsequent requests. You can check it out yourself by doing something like this -

   ```
    db = pymongo.MongoClient()['my_db']
    result = list(db['my_collection'].find(my_query))
    #make another query returning same amount of data
    result_2 = list(db['my_collection'].find(my_query_2))
   ```

   You will find that "result" will take comparatively more time than "result_2". So the execution time for the first request is usually high and not reliable for performance analysis.
3. As you have already mentioned, parsing and converting mongo documents to python objects will also take some time.