# Pymongo read much slower than mongo client(robomongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, pymongo, robo3t

It is very quick to query in robomongo, below pic show I do retrieve 500 doc back:

[image]

I have created index at `result.type`,  my test code:

```
def get_test_data(limit):
    return collection.find({'result.type':'detail'})[:limit]

def test_one_read_multi_process():

    print('mongodb read')
    t = Timer()
    TASKS = list(get_test_data(500))
    print(t.elapsed_time, '\n')
```

pymongo takes 21.716s ,  it is too slow.

test on mongodb 3.6, pymongo latest,  python 2&3

Maybe relate to
[Pymongo significantly slower than mongo shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140183/pymongo-significantly-slower-than-mongo-shell)

But I want a solution .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can install `pymongo` with c extension, to check if you have already done:

```
import pymongo
pymongo.has_c()
```

`False` means not while `True` means yes.

To install `pymongo` with c extension, you need:

```
# Ubuntu or Debian
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev

# Red Hat based distributions
sudo yum install gcc python-devel
```

And then `pip install pymongo`.

There are some reference:

- http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/installation.html#dependencies-for-installing-c-extensions-on-unix
- https://wicknicks.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/pymongo-and-performance/

Comment: `>>> pymongo.has_c()
True`  , it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

So far `get_test_data` gets all the documents in the collection and slices the result.

You want to apply limit to the query.

```
def get_test_data(limit):
    return collection.find({'result.type':'detail'}, limit=limit)
```

Comment: This is equal to slice. As I remanber, older version even not support limit option, only slice. PS: pymongo 's find query is iterable, so slice is fine. That's why I use list(xxx) to convert it.

Comment: No, both are not equal. This answer applies to newer version but then you're using 3.6. From the generated command executed against Mongo server limit is applied to the query when limit is passed https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.6.0/pymongo/message.py#L173