# Reading MongoDB in pandas using Python 3.5

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pandas

My tweets Database, is MongoDB is having the following schema, I want to read this with pandas Dataframe in separate columns. I also want inside components of hashtags- text and indices.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a11200441f0c41f447ce56c"),
        "created" : ISODate("2017-11-19T06:09:06Z"),
        "text" : "#Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer after local bank accounts frozen ,
        "username" : "PennyStocksMomo",
        "hashtags" : [
                {
                        "text" : "Bitcoin",
                        "indices" : [
                                0,
                                8
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "language" : "en",
        "id" : "932128582767296512",
        "followers" : 5715
}
```

"EDIT"

I used the code below.

import pymongo

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.BitCoinDatabase
collection = db.tweets
data = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find()))



_id created followers   hashtags    id  language    text    username
0   5a11200441f0c41f447ce56c    2017-11-19 06:09:06 5715    [{'text': 'Bitcoin', 'indices': [0, 8]}]    932128582767296512  en  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...   PennyStocksMomo
1   5a11200441f0c41f447ce56d    2017-11-19 06:09:06 19526   [{'text': 'Bitcoin', 'indices': [0, 8]}]    932128583077675008  en  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...   CryptoTraderPro
```

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16249736/2901002) should help.

Comment: I am able to read the data, but also needs the text in hashtags and the indices which are shown as in edit.

Comment: In `hashtags` in one row is only one `dict` in `list` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` by column `hashtags` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

*Notice - Solution works if only one `dict` per row in `list` in `hashtags` column.*

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['hashtags'].str[0].values.tolist()).add_suffix('_hash'))
print (df)
                        _id          created followers  \
0  5a11200441f0c41f447ce56c   2017-11-19 06:09:06 5715   
1  5a11200441f0c41f447ce56d  2017-11-19 06:09:06 19526   

                                   hashtags                  id language  \
0  [{'text': 'Bitcoin', 'indices': [0, 8]}]  932128582767296512       en   
1  [{'text': 'Bitcoin', 'indices': [0, 8]}]  932128583077675008       en   

                                                text         username  \
0  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...  PennyStocksMomo   
1  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...  CryptoTraderPro   

  indices_hash text_hash  
0       [0, 8]   Bitcoin  
1       [0, 8]   Bitcoin
```

EDIT:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'

means there are some `NaN`s values.

I try simulate it:

```
print (df)
                        _id          created followers  \
0  5a11200441f0c41f447ce56c   2017-11-19 06:09:06 5715   
1  5a11200441f0c41f447ce56d  2017-11-19 06:09:06 19526   
2  5a11200441f0c41f447ce56c   2017-11-19 06:09:06 5715   

                                   hashtags                  id language  \
0  [{'text': 'Bitcoin', 'indices': [0, 8]}]  932128582767296512       en   
1                                       NaN  932128583077675008       en   
2  [{'text': 'Bitcoin', 'indices': [0, 8]}]  932128582767296512       en   

                                                text         username  
0  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...  PennyStocksMomo  
1  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...  CryptoTraderPro  
2  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...  PennyStocksMomo
```

Solution is first remove `NaNs` and add `index` parameter to `DataFrame` constructor for align data:

```
hashtags = df['hashtags'].dropna()
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(hashtags.str[0].values.tolist(),
             index=hashtags.index).add_suffix('_hash'))
print (df)
                        _id          created followers  \
0  5a11200441f0c41f447ce56c   2017-11-19 06:09:06 5715   
1  5a11200441f0c41f447ce56d  2017-11-19 06:09:06 19526   
2  5a11200441f0c41f447ce56c   2017-11-19 06:09:06 5715   

                                   hashtags                  id language  \
0  [{'text': 'Bitcoin', 'indices': [0, 8]}]  932128582767296512       en   
1                                       NaN  932128583077675008       en   
2  [{'text': 'Bitcoin', 'indices': [0, 8]}]  932128582767296512       en   

                                                text         username  \
0  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...  PennyStocksMomo   
1  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...  CryptoTraderPro   
2  #Bitcoin Hong Kong's bitcoin businesses suffer...  PennyStocksMomo   

  indices_hash text_hash  
0       [0, 8]   Bitcoin  
1          NaN       NaN  
2       [0, 8]   Bitcoin
```

Comment: This is helpful, I upvoted, but It didnt worked in my case.

Comment: What is problem?

Comment: I am using this, df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['hashtags'].str[0].values.tolist()).add_suffix('_hash'))

KEY ERROR HASTAGS, df = data (Dataframe in above code in question)

Comment: It means there is no column `hashtags`, what is `print (df.columns.tolist())`?

Comment: I solved that, now I am here. Please check this.

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: you are using python 2?

Comment: No, I use `python 3` but it is no difference here.