# how to parse data of all collections using pymongo

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz4BS.png)I have a mongodb connection(posted in image),which is having a collection of say some 20 files.
 i would like to read/load each  collection from python and do the necessary computing.

Please find the sample below what i am trying to do.

```html
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from unittest.mock import inplace
from pymongo import MongoClient

connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db=connection.Tmobile
collection=db.collection_names(include_system_collections=False)
for collect1 in collection:
    print(collect1)
    with open(collect1,'r') as fi:
        d=json.load(fi)
        print(d)
```

when i try this it gives me below error.

Mynew
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\esrilka\eclipse-workspace\My First PyDev Project\dbsample.py", line 12, in 
    with open(collect1,'r') as fi:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Mynew'

Comment: Seem to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249736/how-to-import-data-from-mongodb-to-pandas?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), especially you may find the `from odo import odo    
data = odo('mongodb://localhost/db::collection', pd.DataFrame)` interesting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import data from mongodb to pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249736/how-to-import-data-from-mongodb-to-pandas)