# How to load a large JSON file to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-science, ijson

I have 16 JSON files each of them is about 14GB in size. I've tried the following approach to read them line by line.

```
with open(file_name, encoding="UTF-8") as json_file:
cursor = 0
for line_number, line in enumerate(json_file):
    print ("Processing line", line_number + 1,"at cursor index:", cursor)
    line_as_file = io.StringIO(line)
    # Use a new parser for each line
    json_parser = ijson.parse(line_as_file)
    for prefix, type, value in json_parser:
        #print ("prefix=",prefix, "type=",type, "value=",value,ignore_index=True)
        dfObj = dfObj.append({"prefix":prefix,"type":type,"value":value},ignore_index=True)
    cursor += len(line)
```

My aim is to load them into a pandas data frame to perform some search operations.

The problem is that this approach takes a lot of time to read the file.

Is there any other optimal approach to achieve this?

Comment: About loading a json into pandas, did you try `pd.read_json(file_name)`?

Comment: Yes. That loads the whole file into the memory at once which crashes the kernel.

Comment: size might be a deterrent. probably a database would serve u better

Comment: take a look at mongoDB (stores JSONs) and [pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249736/how-to-import-data-from-mongodb-to-pandas). You can get everything out of the JSONs using field names, conditions, searches, etc. Might want to use Dask instead of pandas (very similar syntax) depending on how much RAM you have (pandas df is like 4x file size).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass down `json_file` only once directly to ijson.parse instead of reading individual lines out of it. If your files have more than one top-level JSON value then you can use the `multiple_value=True` option (see [here](https://github.com/ICRAR/ijson#options) for a description).

Also make sure you are using an up-to-date ijson, and that the `yajl2_c` backend is the one in use (in ijson 3 you can see which backend is selected by looking at `ijson.backend`). For information on backends have a look [here](https://github.com/ICRAR/ijson#backends).

Comment: Yes, I did use "multiple_value=True" in my code. I will check out the ijson backend. Thanks!

Comment: This surely did increase the speed but not significantly. The size of the data I have is the bottleneck here. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Another problem that might be dropping performance is how you append data into the DataFrame. Instead of creating it empty and calling `append` you could try a different approach: DataFrame constructor's `data` argument can take an iterable (or so it says [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)), so if you wrap your example code as a generator that yields (prefix, type, value) tuples then you might be able to pass that generator as the data source for the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas builtin function 
pandas.read_json()
The documentation is [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)