# how to move values from pandas columns with dicts into new columns containing just the value

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I had a JSON file that was heavily nested that I normalized into a Pandas dataframe. The result was that all of the keys were turned into columns and the values into rows. The problem is it appears I have some columns that still contain dicts and were not properly normalized. The dataframe has over 8000 rows and 3000 columns so this can't be done by hand.

Here is the JSON file: https://justpaste.it/9nfke

For example:

I have the following column named:

`Return.ReturnData.IRS990PF.AnalysisIncomeProducingActyGrp.OtherRevenueDescribedGrp`

which contains dicts, like the following:

`[{'Desc': 'MISCELLANEOUS', 'ExclusionCd': '01', 'ExclusionAmt': '13'}, {'Desc': 'GRANT REFUNDS', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncmAmt': '159502'}]`

As you can see there's a `Desc` `ExclusionCd` `ExclusionAmt` etc.

I already have populated columns in my dataframes named for these:

`Return.ReturnData.IRS990PF.AnalysisIncomeProducingActyGrp.OtherRevenueDescribedGrp.BusinessCd      Return.ReturnData.IRS990PF.AnalysisIncomeProducingActyGrp.OtherRevenueDescribedGrp.Desc      Return.ReturnData.IRS990PF.AnalysisIncomeProducingActyGrp.OtherRevenueDescribedGrp.ExclusionAmt      Return.ReturnData.IRS990PF.AnalysisIncomeProducingActyGrp.OtherRevenueDescribedGrp.ExclusionCd      Return.ReturnData.IRS990PF.AnalysisIncomeProducingActyGrp.OtherRevenueDescribedGrp.RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncmAmt      Return.ReturnData.IRS990PF.AnalysisIncomeProducingActyGrp.OtherRevenueDescribedGrp.UnrelatedBusinessTaxblIncmAmt`

How can I move those values into their respective columns? Keep in mind that I probably have hundreds of these and I can't do it by hand. It needs to be automated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The posted data shows one record, and it's not clear if the file contains a list of these records.
- With pandas, the best method to use to parse a list of JSON records in `pd.json_normalize`.

  - The sample is to long to post in the answer, but note that all the keys are parsed out and there are no `dict`s as values in a row, when you run this locally.
- This key `Return.ReturnData.IRS990PF` is not available in the PasteBin data sample.

  - Of the `IRS990` keys, only `IRS990` and `IRS990Schedule...` are available.
- Another way to unpack values that are lists of dicts, is with the `meta` parameter of `json_normalize`

  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081799) for a good example

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
from pathlib import Path

# path to file
p = Path('c:\some_path\test.json')

# read in the JSON file
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# parse with pandas
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# if there's a list of dictionaries in the resulting dataframe, they can be unpacked with something like
df['Return.ReturnData.IRS990ScheduleO.SupplementalInformationDetail'].apply(pd.json_normalize)
```

Comment: I would love to experiment with new methods but I spent a huge amount of time cleaning this data (as you might imagine with 40 something million values) so I can't really restart at this point. I will try normalizing specific columns only though. I appreciate the insight.