# how to store and retrieve list of pandas dataframe in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I have a list of dataframes. I want to store these in mongodb and retrieve it.

I tried storing:

```
for every_df in dfs:
   records = json.loads(every_df.to_json()).values()
   db_connection.insert(records)
```

but i'm not sure how to retrieve.

Comment: have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249736/how-to-import-data-from-mongodb-to-pandas?rq=1

Comment: ya i have but not sure how to use it in my case! what does the query mean in the function??

Comment: Well I'm not a mongo expert but you have several options include direct querying, exporting to json or csv and loading

Answer (score 3):

Check out [odo](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/odo). You can do each of these operations (append and retrieve) in a single line, even when you have multiple `DataFrame`s. Here's an example:

```
In [1]: from odo import odo, chunks, resource

In [2]: dfs = (pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b':list('abc')}),
   ...:        pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b':list('def')}))

In [3]: dfs
Out[3]:
(   a  b
 0  1  a
 1  2  b
 2  3  c,    a  b
 0  2  d
 1  3  e
 2  4  f)

In [4]: db = resource('mongodb://localhost/mydb')

In [5]: coll = odo(chunks(pd.DataFrame)(dfs), db.mycollection)

In [6]: list(coll.find())
Out[6]:
[{u'_id': ObjectId('55520638362e690439f13dfb'), u'a': 1, u'b': u'a'},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('55520638362e690439f13dfc'), u'a': 2, u'b': u'b'},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('55520638362e690439f13dfd'), u'a': 3, u'b': u'c'},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('55520638362e690439f13dfe'), u'a': 2, u'b': u'd'},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('55520638362e690439f13dff'), u'a': 3, u'b': u'e'},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('55520638362e690439f13e00'), u'a': 4, u'b': u'f'}]

In [7]: whole_df = odo(coll, pd.DataFrame)

In [8]: whole_df
Out[8]:
   a  b
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
3  2  d
4  3  e
5  4  f
```

Comment: odo also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34483020/4549682), but they said it has problems with non alpha username, password.  Is this true or already fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`MongoClient`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) from `pymongo` and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) from `pandas`.
I'll show the simple case.

Necessary modules

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

create dummy dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['r,'a','n'], 
                   'Z': ['d','o','m']})
```

convert dataframe into a python list of dicts using `to_dict`
Why not `to_json`? I've found `to_dict` handles datetime objects better more consistently.

```
data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

create mongodb connector.

```
cur = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')['yourDATABASE']['yourCOLLECTION'] # assume local instance
```

next we use [`insert_many`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) with the list of dicts

```
cur.insert_many(data)
```

finally we use [`find`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) to retrieve data from `'yourCOLLECTION'` as a cursor object.

```
result = cur.find({})
```

which we loop through with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extract out data as a list of dicts.

```
result = [r for r in result]
```

**Note:** Most of the `MongoClient` collection operators use mongodb simple query format, with all keys as `str`.