# Insert a NumPy rec.array to MongoDB using PyMongo

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, numpy, pandas

In an other question some people are trying to insert a Pandas DataFrame into MongoDB using Python internal structures (`dict`, `list`)
[Insert a Pandas Dataframe into mongodb using PyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167194/insert-a-pandas-dataframe-into-mongodb-using-pymongo)

I wonder if we can't insert instead a NumPy `rec.array` (`numpy.recarray`) to MongoDB using PyMongo.

That should probably be more efficient because `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` use for loops and that very long to process huge volume of data

see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/c45dc762655d7109362fecea05584c72351fdc83/pandas/core/frame.py#L854

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import pymongo
In [3]: client = pymongo.MongoClient()
In [4]: collection = client['db_name']['collection_name']
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
In [7]: rec = df.to_records()
In [8]: rec
Out[8]:
rec.array([(0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 5, 6)],
          dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8')])
In [9]: type(rec)
Out[9]: numpy.recarray
```

but I faced some errors at insert

```
In [10]: collection.insert(rec)
```

raised

```
ValueError: no field of name _id
```

this

```
In [11]: collection.insert_many(rec)
```

raised

```
TypeError: documents must be a non-empty list
```

this

```
In [12]: collection.insert_one(rec)
```

raised

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

[Odo](http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/) can do this

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import pymongo
In [3]: client = pymongo.MongoClient()
In [4]: collection = client['db_name']['collection_name']

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
In [6]: rec = df.to_records(index=False)

In [7]: from odo import odo
In [8]: odo(rec, collection)  # migrate recarray into collection
Out[8]: Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), 'db_name'), 'collection_name')

In [9]: list(collection.find())
Out[9]: 
[{'_id': ObjectId('56801e0bfb5d1b19ff9b9dd3'), 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
 {'_id': ObjectId('56801e0bfb5d1b19ff9b9dd4'), 'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
```

However it just goes through an iterator of dictionaries (and so is as inefficient as the other solutions in this regard).  If you really want to send binary data efficiently over then you should look at [monary](https://monary.readthedocs.org/).

But  for loops aren't necessarily the bottleneck here.  I highly recommend doing some simple benchmarking to verify that converting to Python data structures here is the bottleneck of your application.  You may be optimizing prematurely.

Comment: I wonder what path `odo` use to achieve this ? According what you are saying it's not using monary.

Comment: Last time I was involved with odo it would have converted to an iterator of python dicts.