# How to store datasets and databases from quandl using quandl Python API/module in postgresql or mongodb?

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql, python-3.x, quandl

Does anybody know how to use quandl module/API for Python to store datasets and databases into a single database using postgresql or mongodb. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem, you can upvote and accept it. Otherwise, I am happy to continue to help you if you elaborate on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The data returned from the quandl API are pandas dataframes.

You can save pandas dataframes to mongodb like this using `PyMongo`:

```
df = quandl.get("FRED/GDP",returns="pandas")
records = json.loads(df.T.to_json()).values()
db.myCollection.insert(records)
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167194/insert-a-pandas-dataframe-into-mongodb-using-pymongo) for more information

To write to a SQL database, you can use the `to_sql` method on the pandas dataframe. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103962/how-to-write-dataframe-to-postgres-table) for more information