# Process the data in the database and write to a new table

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb

The problem I'm having is processing a table in the database and then merging all to write to another table.

The table structure is like this:

[image]

Owns 3 database tables.

I want to merge into the table by the Entryid

My idea is to extract the data with pandas and process.

But there are many problems writing to the database.

Below is the code I tried:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import pymongo


def data_Process():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(host="mongodb://localhost:27017/")

    collection1 = client.test.declare_customs
    collection2 = client.test.tax
    collection3 = client.test.ship
    collection4 = client.test.jieguan

    data1 = pd.DataFrame(list(collection1.find()))
    data2 = pd.DataFrame(list(collection2.find()))
    data3 = pd.DataFrame(list(collection3.find()))
    data3 = data3.groupby(by=['entryId']).agg(';'.join)

    data4 = pd.merge(data1, data2, on='entryId', how='left')
    data5 = pd.merge(data4, data3, on='entryId', how='left')

    data5.to_excel('data5.xlsx')
    collection4.insert(data5)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_Process()
```

Error:
[image]

If you have a better idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did following that error message lead you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below answer,

[Insert a Pandas Dataframe into mongodb using PyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167194/insert-a-pandas-dataframe-into-mongodb-using-pymongo)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167984/3704501

You need to convert the pandas dataframe into json format before inserting into mongo collection

Comment: hi,I know the reason
`
    data3 = pd.DataFrame(list(collection3.find()))
    if True:
        del data3['_id']
`
I need to remove the ID from the data exported by mongodb

Comment: @hakukou `if True`? You shouldn’t delete columns using `del` by the way, use `drop()`.

Comment: @Alexander Cécile hi,Yes i need to delete '_id'

Comment: @hakukou Where is the `if True` coming from? Use [`.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to remove the column.

Comment: @Alexander Cécile if True not required, yes i used .drop(columns='_id')  thank you very much

Comment: @hakukou You’re welcome :) Everything is clear now?

Comment: #Alexander Cécile Yes i understand :)