# Difficulty with document batch import, pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm having a much more difficult time than I thought I would importing multiple documents from Mongo into RAM in batch. I am writing an application to communicate with a MongoDB via `pymongo` that currently has 2GBs, but in the near future could grow to over 1TB. Because of this, batch reading a limited number of records into RAM at a time is important for scalability.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786736/how-to-read-through-collection-in-chunks-by-1000]) and [this documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.7.2/api/pymongo/cursor.html) I thought this would be about as easy as:

```
HOST = MongoClient(MONGO_CONN)
DB_CONN = HOST.database_name
collection = DB_CONN.collection_name
cursor = collection.find()
cursor.batch_size(1000) 
next_1K_records_in_RAM = cursor.next()
```

This isn't working for me, however. Even though I have a Mongo collection populated with >200K BSON objects, this reads them in one at a time as single dictionaries, e.g. `{_id : ID1, ...}` instead of what I'm looking for, which is an error of dictionaries representing multiple documents in my collections, e.g. `[{_id : ID1, ...}, {_id : ID2, ...}, ..., {_id: ID1000, ...}]`.

I wouldn't expect this to matter, but I'm on python 3.5 instead of 2.7.

As this example references a secure, remote data source this isn't a reproducible example. Apologies for that. If you have a suggestion for how the question can be improved please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Python version is irrelevant here, nothing to do with your output.
- Batch_size defines only how many documents mongoDB returns in a single
  trip to DB (under some limitations: [see here
  here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) )
- collection.find always returns an iterator/cursor or None. Batching does its job transparently)
  (the later if no documents are found)
- To examine returned documents you
  have to iterate through the cursor i.e.

  `For document in cursor:
     print (document)`

  or if you want a list of the documents: `list(cursor)`

  - Remember to do a `cursor.rewind()` if you need to revisit the documents

Comment: OK, so if I want to create an iterator that returns 1000 docs at a time from the DB in my local RAM how do I do that?

Comment: collection.find({...}, limit=1000)

Comment: @nickmilon I suppose `limit=1000` will only return 1000 documents from the db (and then cursor will be exhausted). How can I iterate over the whole collection by the batches of 1000, so that `records.next()` will return lists with len = 1000?

Comment: no mongoDB option for that, but you can handle it in your code
a) use limit and  repeat the find with a kind of paging mechanism in the query.
b)  l = list(db.collection.find({,,,}) 
     sl = [l[x:x+1000] for x in range(0, len(l), 1000)]
for i in sl:print(i)
* but make sure your memory can handle those big lists